# Kernel of the linear map $T: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $(Tp)(x) = x^2 p(x)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

In Example 3.13, Axler discusses the null space of the linear map $T: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ (where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of polynomials with real coefficients) defined by $(Tp)(x) = x^2 p(x)$. He argues that the null space consists only of the $0$ polynomial. I don't understand why this is the case.

The $0$ polynomial is certainly in the null space. We have $(T 0)(x) = x^2 0(x) = x^2 \cdot 0 = 0$. The converse direction is not clear to me. Let's suppose that $p \in \text{null } T$. Then $(Tp)(x) = x^2 p(x) = 0$. Axler argues that the only $p$ such that this is true for all $x$ is the $0$ polynomial. I'm having trouble understanding why that's the case. I tried writing $p(x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ and multiplying the expression out. I get:
$$
x^2 p(x) = x^2 \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i x^i = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i x^{i+2}.
$$
So every monomial on the left-hand side has degree greater than or equal to $2$. Is the only remaining piece to this argument equating coefficients and arguing that $a_i = 0$ for all $i$ because the polynomial on the right-hand side is the zero polynomial?

Comment: If $x^{2}p(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then either $f(x) = x$ is $0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (which is obviously not the case) or $p(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: "Is the only piece...?" - yes.  But you probably should be aware that the product of two polynomials is never the zero polynomial unless one factor is (or both are) the zero polynomial, and this gives you a much simpler argument.